# How to display image Array in Retrofit?

Tags: image, retrofit

Below my Response and Adapter class how to display in adapter class to set image in adapter class and display image array in that adapter class how can possible to display that image in adapter class

Thanks

Response :--

```
{
      "data": [
        {
          "album_id": "2",
          "album_name": "txt_neeraj",
          "date": "2016/07/29",
          "image": [
            "../media/images/wedding/pin.png",
            "../media/images/wedding/slideshow-phone.png",
            "../media/images/wedding/test.png",
            "../media/images/wedding/Untitled.png",
            "../media/images/wedding/021Jul16_11423442.png",
            "../media/images/wedding/121Jul16_11423442.png",
            "../media/images/wedding/221Jul16_11423442.png",
            "../media/images/wedding/321Jul16_11423442.png",
            "../media/images/wedding/421Jul16_11423442.png"
          ],
          "email": "neerajnj.gems@gmail.com",
          "wedd_key": "UGYFTRFT"
        },
        {
          "album_id": "3",
          "album_name": "Wedding",
          "date": "10/12/1991",
          "image": [
            "../media/images/wedding/Untitled.png",
            "../media/images/wedding/test.png",
            "../media/images/wedding/test.png",
            "../media/images/wedding/Untitled.png",
            "../media/images/wedding/021Jul16_11423442.png",
            "../media/images/wedding/121Jul16_11423442.png",
            "../media/images/wedding/221Jul16_11423442.png",
            "../media/images/wedding/321Jul16_11423442.png",
            "../media/images/wedding/421Jul16_11423442.png"
          ],
          "email": "jalpesh1012@gmail.com",
          "wedd_key": "UGYFTRFT"
        },
    ],
      "status": "100"
    }
```

Adapter Class SetImage:----

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    ImageUtils.getImageLoader(mContext).
            displayImage(Constant.PENDING_IMG_URL + mTimelineData.get(position).getT_images(),
                    holder.imgEvent);
    ImageUtils.getImageLoader(mContext).
            displayImage(Constant.PENDING_IMG_URL + mTimelineData.get(position).getT_images(),
                    holder.imgMain);
    ImageUtils.getImageLoader(mContext).
            displayImage(Constant.PENDING_IMG_URL + mTimelineData.get(position).getT_images(),
                    holder.imgOne);
    ImageUtils.getImageLoader(mContext).
            displayImage(Constant.PENDING_IMG_URL + mTimelineData.get(position).getT_images(),
                    holder.imgTwo);
    ImageUtils.getImageLoader(mContext).
            displayImage(Constant.PENDING_IMG_URL + mTimelineData.get(position).getT_images(),
                    holder.imgThree);

    holder.txtDate.setText(mTimelineData.get(position).getT_date());
    if(mTimelineData.get(position).getT_desc().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
        holder.txtDescrption.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else{
        holder.txtDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.txtDescrption.setText(mTimelineData.get(position).getT_desc());
    }
    holder.txtHeader.setText(mTimelineData.get(position).getT_name());
}
```

Comment: From what I can see all links are relative... is this what you want? Looks weird to me that an api would send relative image links to clients.

Comment: I want to just display "image": [
            "../media/images/wedding/Untitled.png",
            "../media/images/wedding/test.png"]